# Why Tab Indent is not Consistent in VSCode ? (Dart Language)

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I want to ask about the "Format Document" feature, why when using the "document format" feature in VScode, the tabulation becomes irregular like the code that I attached below.

I have tried to set "Editor: tab size" to 2 but when I use "Format Document", my code becomes irregular.

`````````````````
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
````return new Container(
````````child: new Column(
``````children: <Widget>[
````````new Row(
``````````children: <Widget>[
````````````//slideshow
````````````new Expanded(
````````````````child: new CarouselSlider(
``````````````height: 150.0,
`````````````````

I expect the code like this :

`````````````````
@override
``Widget build(BuildContext context) {
````return new Container(
``````child: new Column(
````````children: <Widget>[
``````````new Row(
````````````children: <Widget>[
``````````````//slideshow
``````````````new Expanded(
````````````````child: new CarouselSlider(
````````````````height: 150.0,
`````````````````

Comment: It sucks that nobody answered the actual question you answered. That jagged auto-formatting outdenting has been driving me crazy, for months, now in 2022, and I haven't found any setting that can change it to the sensible indents you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting is done by [dart_style/dartfmt](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style), and its convention is 2-space indenting, with [4 spaces for continued lines](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/Formatting-Rules#%5CQindent-continued-lines-with-at-least-four-spaces%5CE).

For Flutter code this often isn't the best formatting, so trailing commas can be used to change the formatting a little that works better:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas

[image]
<sub>(source: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/assets/tools/android-studio/trailing-comma-with-1d6907af995766eb14afba227e3c54d015fc02a2c15bc1779cae60696660c72e.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

After poking around for solutions to this for months, thinking it must have something to do with the line length, the word wrapping, or other things, and none of it worked, I realized that if one has "Enable SDK Formatter" checked, it will seemingly override all of that with dart_style's choices.

Kind of sad to turn it off, as I'm sure it must be doing some other things that are useful. But I just can't live with that odd formatting that obfuscates the actual structure of the code as soon as I hit Save. So, if you're doing it manually in the settings.json, I would do:

"dart.enableSdkFormatter": false,